# Node red String single value extraction

Tags: node-red

Sorry I know this will be a total beginner question on node-red but we are trying to integrate single variables from a string which originates from an MQTT server. I've seen some explanations but toil to understand what I actually need to do.

the string I get in the debug window output is:

> owntracks/user/xxxxxxx : msg.payload : string [168]
>   {"tst":1480614621,"acc":65,"_type":"location","alt":141,"lon":-3.496676232329715,"vac":10,"p":101.0898056030273,"lat":55.90523658856472,"batt":49,"conn":"m","tid":"NH"}

This message comes from the MQTT node and I have connected simply to msg.payload see the output. I have seen things relating to splitters and functions but could anyone send an example of what the code is to split the three numbers out of the string so I can simply have these as standalone numbers.

I want to be able to extract the "lat" as a single number or message, the "lon" as a single number or message and the "alt" as a single number or message so I can then use these three standalone numbers in another application.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what you want to do with those values later, but if you wire the MQTT node to an instance of the JSON node it will parse that string into a JSON object that you can then access like any other JSON object.

E.g. if you then wire the JSON node to a function node the following code will get you the variables:

```
var lat = msg.payload.lat;
var lon = msg.payload.lon;
var alt = msg.payload.alt;

....
```